# .NetCore Api Docker Image is not working when pulled from DockerHub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Created a .net core (3.1) API which depends on MongoDB and created a docker image for this project (which is working fine in my system). I am pushing this image to a private repository.

When pulling the image from another system/host/machine, The image is not working and giving error `exited with code 0`
I am very new to Docker and not finding how to pull the image to a new system and start using it.
Below are the steps I did.
Using Docker-Compose.yml to create supported images.

these are the images created in my system.

[image]

Commands I am using to tag the image and push

```
docker tag 9aa28f48b025 myusername/reponame
docker push myusername/reponame
```

Commands I am using to pull in another system.

```
docker login -- (using credentials)
docker pull myusername/reponame
```

Is my understanding of reusing images wrong? Any reference or suggestion will be a great help

Comment: Are you saying that you run the docker compose - it works. Then you upload the image to dockerhub, download it to the same host, run the docker-compose again (with the same image that you have just pushed/pulled) and it doesn't work?

Comment: @MatusDubrava upload image to docker hub, download it to a different host. trying to run that image. it doesn't work

Comment: @MatusDubrava updated the question to make more sense. I am just pulling the image to another machine, I am expecting it to work when I run it as a container.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer this question because there is just to many moving parts that can cause the issue. Docker is not a VM and while it works pretty well in general from the compatibility perspective, there are edge cases, especially when you are using windows based containers because it still relies on the underlying OS. I would suggest running just a simple container from the pulled image with `docker run` and see whether it shows the same behavior as when you run it on the former host.